# how to use multiple texture objLoader, mtlLoader in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, objloader

I can able to visible object but don't work multiple material textures images. It's visible black color. what is missing in my code?

```
  case 'plant':   
  var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
  mtlLoader.setPath('models/LivingRoom/Sample1/');
  mtlLoader.load( '3dbts103601T.mtl', function( materials ) {
  materials.preload();  

  var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
  loader.setPath('models/LivingRoom/Sample1/');   
  loader.load('3dbts103601T.obj', function (object) {

    var geometry = object.children[ 0 ].geometry;   
    var materials = []; 
    var mat1=new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map : THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('models/LivingRoom/Sample1/3dbts103601T1.jpg')});
    var mat2=new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map : THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('models/LivingRoom/Sample1/3dbts103601T2.jpg')});

    materials.push(mat1);
    materials.push(mat2);
    Mesh = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geometry,materials);    

       object.traverse(function (child) {
        if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                child.materials = materials;

        }
        });
        scene1.add(object);
  });
  });   
  break;
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity, in that line `child.materials = materials;`, where did you find the `.materials` property of `THREE.Mesh()` from?

Comment: if you multiple materials textures using `child.materials` working well.ok. my object visible only black color. What mistake in my code? please give any idea @prisoner849

Comment: AFAIK, `THREE.Mesh()` has `.material` property, there is no `.materials`.

Comment: if I use `child.material` object not visible. ok. How to use multiple Textures using objLoader? Please tell me. I tried the lot.  @prisoner849

Comment: Did u solve the problem?